# What is a DList?

Tags: list, scala, data-structures, append, scalaz

I tried googling for this but all I got were stories about minor celebrities. Given the lack of documentation, what is a [DList](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/DList.scala)?

Comment: I only clicked on this question for a chance to make a facetious comment about celebrities.  But it was already there in the question... +1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a Difference List, along the lines of ["Difference List as functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_list)

```
scala> val (l1, l2, l3) = (List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
l2: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
l3: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9)
```

Efficient prepending:

```
scala> l1 ::: l2 ::: l3
res8: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Inefficient appending. This creates an intermediate list (l1 ++ l2), then ((l1 ++ l2) ++ l3)

```
scala> l1 ++ l2 ++ l3  // inefficient
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

`DList` stores up the appends, and only needs to create one complete list, effectively invoking:

```
scala> List(l1, l2, l3) reduceRight ( _ ::: _) 
res10: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: Isn't prepending regular Scala lists with ::: still linear in the length of the prefixes? Or is there some additional code that exploits their immutability to do better?

Comment: With a `DList`, the total operation is still `O(n * m)`, where `n` is number of chunks and `m` is the chunk size. With `++`, the operation is `O(n * n * m)`

Answer (score 13):

Difference lists are a list-like data structure that supports *O(1)* append operations.

Append, and other operations that modify a list are represented via function composition of the modification functions, rather than directly copying the list.

An example, from [Haskell's dlist library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist):

```
-- Lists as functions
newtype DList a = DL { unDL :: [a] -> [a] }

-- The empty list
empty       = DL id

-- The append case: composition, a la Hughes
append xs ys = DL (unDL xs . unDL ys)

-- Converting to a regular list, linear time.
toList      = ($[]) . unDL
```

The technique goes back at least to [Hughes 84](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/john-hughes/lists.pdf), *A novel representation of lists and its application to the function "reverse"*, R. John Hughes, 1984., where, he proposes representing lists as functions, and append as function composition, allowing e.g. reverse to run in linear time. From the paper:

---

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: It would be good to add an `a -> DList a` example: `singleton = \a -> DL ((:) a)`

Answer (score 3):

It's a data type in the non-canonical [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) package, useful for typed lists with constant-time access at both ends. (The trick is to google for "scala" AND "dlist".)

Comment: I assumed it was non-scala-specific

Comment: DList were found to overflow the stack and were deleted from Scalaz: http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/issues/detail?id=19

Comment: @WillSargent DList was added back to Scalaz in 2011 https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/0c299ee4c15049310f2a5b229f46f5d5621d6702

Answer (score 1):

From the [project page of scalaz](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/):

> DList, a data type for representing elements of the same type with constant time append/prepend operations.