# Concatenate lists in constant time in scala?

Tags: list, scala, data-structures, concatenation

In Scala, is there a built-in function or external library for concatenating two lists (or arrays, or vectors, or listbuffers, etc) in constant time? Such an operation would presumably destroy / mutate the two original lists. All the functions I see for concatenating lists run in linear time, as far as I can tell.

Thanks much.

Comment: How could you possibly copy N (i.e. a variable number of) items in constant time?

Comment: @delnan: He didn't ask to copy the values. For example, you can join two binary trees in constant time by creating a new root with the two trees as the child nodes. (You'd have to see 'list' with the loose meaning of 'sequence' in this case.)

Comment: See if you can make of use of a DList. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352418/what-is-a-dlist. Eventually you'll still need a linear operation to construct the final list, but it's probably the closest to something readily available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is the [`UnrolledBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/UnrolledBuffer.html) which has the `concat` method taking another `UnrolledBuffer` and returning their concatenation in `O(1)`. It is destructive to the argument buffer - the second buffer will be empty after this calling this method.

Answer (score 2):

The classic (going back to at least [Hughes '84](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/john-hughes/lists.pdf)) approach in functional languages to solve constant-time append in is via ["difference lists"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_list), where appending to the list is encoded as function composition.

Here's a sketch in Haskell:

```
newtype DList a = DL { unDL :: [a] -> [a] }
```

So a DList is a function from lists to lists. Some introduction forms:

```
-- The empty list is the identity function
empty       = DL id    

-- Singletons are the compositions of the cons function
singleton   = DL . (:)

-- Appending two lists is just composition
append xs ys = DL (unDL xs . unDL ys)
```

The full implementation is [on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist), and should be trivial to translate to Scala.

Comment: I believe scalaz has a DList implementation. http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/ though I can't find it on github.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking that a `DoubleLinkedList` could offer a constant-time append, since you could join the end of one list to the beginning of another without having to traverse either one.

However, neither the `scala.collections.mutable.DoubleLinkedList` or `java.util.List` work that way.

The reason is probably that it would mean `a.append(b)` would modify both **a** and **b**, which would be unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple immutable data structure that supports constant time concatenation. It just shows that it is possible, but is not intended for practical use. The `items` implementation to retrieve the elements has a pretty bad run-time and could easily be improved by walking the tree with an iterator.

I'm wondering if there are any better data structures?

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T] {
  def items: List[T]
  def append[U >: T](v: U): Tree[U] = this append Leave(v)
  def append[U >: T](other: Tree[U]) = Node(this, other)
}

case class Node[+T](val left: Tree[T], val right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {
  def items = left.items ++ right.items
}

case class Leave[+T](val value: T) extends Tree[T] {
  def items = List(value)
}

case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing] {
  def items = Nil
}

object ConstantTimeConcatenation {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val first = EmptyTree append 1 append 2 append 3
    val second = EmptyTree append 4 append 5
    val both = first append second // runs in linear time
    println(both.items)
  }
}
```