# Data.Sequence vs. Data.DList for appending data to the end of the list

Tags: list, haskell, append

I'm writing some code that needs to frequently append to the end of a list. I know that using "++" is inefficient. So instead I build up the list backwards by appending to the head, and then reverse it when I'm done. I gather that this a common beginner tactic.

I would rather build it up in the correct order to begin with - but that means switching to a new data structure. I'm considering using Data.Sequence or Data.DList for my container. My list consists of strict int pairs, and I don't need random access to it. What are the relative merits of Data.Sequence and Data.DList, and are there other containers I should consider?

Comment: I would use `Data.Sequence`, just because it has no external dependecies except `containers`, which is shipped with the standard platform.

Comment: @FUZxxl `DList` implementation is so trivial that it can be used without external dependencies (like `type DList a = [a] -> [a]`, `append = (.)`, `toList = ($[])`, `fromList = (++)` and so on).

Comment: Maybe you could post some of the code to let us know, what kind of solution you need.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352418/what-is-a-dlist/6317209#6317209 for the origins of dlists.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Whether to use `Data.Sequence` or `DList` depends on how you are going to be using the resulting list.  `DList` is great when you are building up a sequence, say in a `Writer` computation, to convert to a list at the end and use it.  However, if you need to use the intermediate results, like, say:

```
f (foo ++ bar)
+ f (foo ++ bar ++ baz)
+ f (foo ++ bar ++ baz ++ quux)
```

then `DList` is pretty bad, because it needs to recompute the spine each time.  `Data.Sequence` is a better choice in this situation.  `Data.Sequence` is also better if you need to remove elements from the sequence.

But maybe you don't even need to make this decision.  Reversing lists at the end of a computation is common in strict functional languages like ML and Scheme, but not in Haskell.  Take, for example, these two ways of writing `map`:

```
map_i f xs = reverse $ go [] xs
    where
    go accum [] = accum
    go accum (x:xs) = go (f x : accum) xs

map_ii f [] = []
map_ii f (x:xs) = f x : map_ii f xs
```

In a strict language, `map_ii` would be horrible because it uses linear stack space, whereas `map_i` is tail recursive.  But because Haskell is lazy, `map_i` is the inefficient one.  `map_ii` can consume one element of the input and yield one element of the output, whereas `map_i` consumes the whole input before yielding any output.

Tail recursion isn't the holy grail of efficient implementation in Haskell.  When producing a data structure like a list, you actually want to be *co*-recursive; that is, make the recursive call underneath an application of a constructor (eg. `f x : map_ii f xs` above).

So if you find yourself reversing after a tail-recursive function, see if you can factor the whole lot into a corecursive function.

Comment: Very helpful answer, Thanks! I am just converting to a list at the end, and I don't need intermediate results. So it sounds like DList is the way for me to go in this case.

Comment: This great answer is the most straightforward definition of corecursion I've seen. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also mention in what situations would `DList` be a better choice?

Comment: @kizzx2, see first paragraph.  In the situations mentioned there, `Data.Sequence` is a waste.

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple criterion comparison:

```
let mdata = replicate 1000 (replicate 100 (13 :: Int))
let f1 = foldl' (++) []
let fr = foldr (++) []
let f2 = foldl' (\s next -> s Seq.|> next) mempty
let f3 = foldl' (DL.snoc) mempty

defaultMain [
    bgroup "time encode" [ bench "++ - foldl"   $ nf (AE.encode . f1) mdata
                         , bench "++ - foldr"   $ nf (AE.encode . fr) mdata
                         , bench "Seq |>"  $ nf (AE.encode . toList . f2) mdata
                         ,  bench "DList snoc"  $ nf (AE.encode . DL.toList . f3) mdata]
  ]
```

With the result:

```
benchmarking time encode/++ - foldl
time                 604.1 ms   (570.0 ms .. 654.6 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (NaN R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 619.2 ms   (608.9 ms .. 625.6 ms)
std dev              9.761 ms   (0.0 s .. 11.21 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking time encode/++ - foldr
time                 2.554 ms   (2.503 ms .. 2.610 ms)
                     0.995 R²   (0.990 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 2.584 ms   (2.547 ms .. 2.628 ms)
std dev              134.1 μs   (111.7 μs .. 186.6 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 34% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking time encode/Seq |>
time                 2.020 ms   (1.986 ms .. 2.049 ms)
                     0.997 R²   (0.995 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 2.106 ms   (2.078 ms .. 2.138 ms)
std dev              105.8 μs   (85.60 μs .. 130.5 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 34% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking time encode/DList snoc
time                 1.992 ms   (1.952 ms .. 2.034 ms)
                     0.996 R²   (0.994 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 2.030 ms   (2.000 ms .. 2.060 ms)
std dev              97.88 μs   (82.60 μs .. 122.3 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 34% (moderately inflated)
```

Conclusion: Use `Data.Sequence`. It has the most flexibility while just a notch lower performance than `DList` - it's probably not worth it.