# Size of a Scalaz DList?

Tags: scala, scalaz

So I finally found a nice functional data structure, Scalaz `DList`, for constant prepend/append and a good complexity for concatenating two collections, however why doesn't `DList`have a size or length member method, and how do I calculate its size?

An `isEmpty` function would do as well.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably because under the hood, `DLists` are functions that only construct a list at the end, rather than building one up as elements are appended

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3352418/215924 for some more about difflists

Comment: @MrBones, yeah I read that thread and I understand that if it would be easy to do, they would have a method for it. However, do you know of any way to calculate the size or if the `DList` is empty in constant time and if so, could you post it as an answer?