# Extracting data from a function chain without arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, functional-programming

This is an advanced topic of

[How to store data of a functional chain of Monoidal List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297054/how-to-store-data-of-a-functional-chain-of-monoidal-list)

I am pretty sure we can somehow extract data from a function chain without using an array storing data.
The basic structure is :

```
L = a => L
```

very simple, but this structure generates a list:

```
L(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)()
```

This may be related to 
[What is a DList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352418/what-is-a-dlist)
, but this structure strictly depends on function chain only.

So, what is the way to pull out the whole values?
Current achievement of mine merely pulling out the head and tail, and I don't know how to fix this.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention what I try to do is

### List.fold(f) / reduce(f)

operation.

So, if one choses `f` as `Array.concat` which means you can extract data as an array, but simply fold is not limited to array concatenation. and `f` can be add/sum etc.

So, currently, so far, to visualize the internal behavior, in a sense, I write `log` as `f`.

EDIT2

I must clarify more. The specification can be presented:

```
const f = (a) => (b) => a + b;//binary operation

A(a)(b)(f) = f(a)(b)  // a + b

A(a)(b)(c)(f) = f(f(a)(b))(c) // a + b + c
```

So this is exactly

```
(a b c).reduce(f)
```

thing, and when

```
f = (a) => (b) => a.concat(b)
```

The result would be `[a, b, c]`.

`Array.concat` is merely a member of generalized binary operations `f`.

At first this challenge is easy for my skill, but turned out hard and felt it's better to ask smarter coder.

Thanks.

```js
const A = a => {

    const B = b => (b === undefined)
        ? (() => {
            log("a " + a);
            return A();
        })()
        : c => (c === undefined)
            ? (() => {
                log("b " + b);
                return B()();
            })()
            : B;

    return B;

};
 

A(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)()

function log(m)  {
    console.log((m)); //IO
    return m;
};
```

### result:

```
b 6
a 1
a undefined
```

Comment: Anyway, my concern is how you return such data if it's not in a array-like data structure?

Comment: This feels very abstract and pointless. What's the actual application here?

Comment: About my previous question: I see how iterator protocol may assist on this if you don't want an array, but at least, you need a sequence, am I mistaken?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks a lot for your contribution again. Sorry I really forgot to mention the important thing. This is to implement `fold` of list. Generalized. I have edit my question, too/

Comment: Given `A(a)(b)(f)` how would you know whether `f` is a value to be added to the list or a reducing function?

Comment: @bayesian-study Uhm I see. BTW it could be implemented with closures as the answered has already pointed out.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks again! I post my own answer that is work in progress. Please review it, too. In this case, for simplicity, `f` is just distinguished by `type of` operation

Comment: @AaditMShah Yeah, hello thanks again! as I mentioned above, in this case, simply, to distinguish  by type of "function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an expression like `A(a)(b)(f)` where `f` is a function, it's impossible to know whether `f` is supposed to be added to the list or whether it's the reducing function. Hence, I'm going to describe how to write expressions like `A(a)(b)(f, x)` which is equivalent to `[a, b].reduce(f, x)`. This allows us to distinguish when the list ends depending upon how many arguments you provide:

```js
const L = g => function (x, a) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
    case 1: return L(k => g((f, a) => k(f, f(a, x))));
    case 2: return g((f, a) => a)(x, a);
    }
};

const A = L(x => x);

const xs = A(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);

console.log(xs((x, y) => x + y, 0));        // 15
console.log(xs((x, y) => x * y, 1));        // 120
console.log(xs((a, x) => a.concat(x), [])); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

It works due to continuations. Every time we add a new element, we accumulate a CPS function. Each CPS function calls the previous CPS function, thereby creating a CPS function chain. When we give this CPS function chain a base function, it unrolls the chain and allows us to reduce it. It's the same idea behind [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) and [lenses](https://www.twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/cps-functional-references).

---

**Edit:** [user633183's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51460654/783743) is brilliant. It uses the [Church encoding of lists using right folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Represent_the_list_using_right_fold) to alleviate the need for continuations, resulting in simpler code which is easy to understand. Here's her solution, modified to make `foldr` seem like `foldl`:

```js
const L = g => function (x, a) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
    case 1: return L((f, a) => f(g(f, a), x));
    case 2: return g(x, a);
    }
};

const A = L((f, a) => a);

const xs = A(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);

console.log(xs((x, y) => x + y, 0));        // 15
console.log(xs((x, y) => x * y, 1));        // 120
console.log(xs((a, x) => a.concat(x), [])); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Here `g` is the Church encoded list accumulated so far. Initially, it's the empty list. Calling `g` folds it from the right. However, we also build the list from the right. Hence, it seems like we're building the list and folding it from the left because of the way we write it.

---

If all these functions are confusing you, what user633183 is really doing is:

```js
const L = g => function (x, a) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
    case 1: return L([x].concat(g));
    case 2: return g.reduceRight(x, a);
    }
};

const A = L([]);

const xs = A(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);

console.log(xs((x, y) => x + y, 0));        // 15
console.log(xs((x, y) => x * y, 1));        // 120
console.log(xs((a, x) => a.concat(x), [])); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

As you can see, she is building the list backwards and then using `reduceRight` to fold the backwards list backwards. Hence, it looks like you're building and folding the list forwards.

Comment: This is truly awesome! honestly, in this moment, I don't understand the concept behind this, but I am grateful to what you have shown me today. I love your attitude to programming and people. Very inspiring!

Comment: Could you please give me a version of a single parameter with the initial element as the default value?? I tried by myself, but I could not make it.

Comment: so far,  `const isFunction = f => (typeof f === 'function')` would be fine to distinguish the evaluation trigger. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I post another Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427797/a-b-reducef-x-code-to-a-b-reducef-using-transducer-cps-based-functional please review it when you have time!

Comment: Based on this jsPerf https://jsperf.com/l-vs-array/1, I believe that this is an experiment in terms of optimization. I don't know about the perf in a functional language which might include optimizations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485931/church-encoding-of-lists-using-right-folds-and-difference-lists This is a new topic related to this topic. Please review, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Quite the series of questions you have here. Here's my take on it:

We start with a way to construct lists

- `nil` is a constant which represents the empty list
- `cons (x, list)` constructs a new list with `x` added to the front of `list`

```js
// nil : List a
const nil =
  (c, n) => n

// cons : (a, List a) -> List a
const cons = (x, y = nil) =>
  (c, n) => c (y (c, n), x)

// list : List Number
const myList = 
  cons (1, cons (2, cons (3, cons (4, nil))))

console.log (myList ((x, y) => x + y, 0))
// 10
```

And to satisfy your golfy variadic curried interface, here is `autoCons`

```js
const autoCons = (init, n) => 
{ const loop = acc => (x, n) =>
    isFunction (x)
      ? acc (x, n)
      : loop (cons (x, acc))
  return loop (nil) (init, n)
}

const isFunction = f =>
  f != null && f.constructor === Function && f.length === 2

const nil =
  (c, n) => n

const cons = (x, y = nil) =>
  (c, n) => c (y (c, n), x)

console.log
  ( autoCons (1) ((x,y) => x + y, 0)             // 1
  , autoCons (1) (2) ((x,y) => x + y, 0)         // 3
  , autoCons (1) (2) (3) ((x,y) => x + y, 0)     // 6
  , autoCons (1) (2) (3) (4) ((x,y) => x + y, 0) // 10
  )
```

Our encoding makes it possible to write other generic list functions, like `isNil`

```
// isNil : List a -> Bool
const isNil = l =>
  l ((acc, _) => false, true)

console.log
  ( isNil (autoCons (1))     // false
  , isNil (autoCons (1) (2)) // false
  , isNil (nil)              // true
  )
```

Or like `length`

```
// length : List a -> Int
const length = l =>
  l ((acc, _) => acc + 1, 0)

console.log
  ( length (nil)                  // 0
  , length (autoCons (1))         // 1
  , length (autoCons (1) (2))     // 2
  , length (autoCons (1) (2) (3)) // 3
  )
```

Or `nth` which fetches the *nth* item in the list

```
// nth : Int -> List a -> a
const nth = n => l =>
  l ( ([ i, res ], x) =>
        i === n
          ? [ i + 1, x ]
          : [ i + 1, res]
    , [ 0, undefined ]
    ) [1]

console.log
  ( nth (0) (autoCons ("A") ("B") ("C")) // "A"
  , nth (1) (autoCons ("A") ("B") ("C")) // "B"
  , nth (2) (autoCons ("A") ("B") ("C")) // "C"
  , nth (3) (autoCons ("A") ("B") ("C")) // undefined
  )
```

We can implement functions like `map` and `filter` for our list

```
// map : (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
const map = f => l =>
  l ( (acc, x) => cons (f (x), acc)
    , nil
    )

// filter : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> List a
const filter = f => l =>
  l ( (acc, x) => f (x) ? cons (x, acc) : acc
    , nil
    )
```

We can even make a program using our list which takes a list as an argument

```
// rcomp : (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
const rcomp = (f, g) =>
  x => g (f (x))

// main : List String -> String   
const main = letters =>
  autoCons (map (x => x + x))
           (filter (x => x !== "dd"))
           (map (x => x.toUpperCase()))
           (rcomp, x => x)
           (letters)
           ((x, y) => x + y, "")

main (autoCons ("a") ("b") ("c") ("d") ("e"))
// AABBCCEE
```

Run the program in your browser below

```js
const nil =
  (c, n) => n

const cons = (x, y = nil) =>
  (c, n) => c (y (c, n), x)

const isFunction = f =>
  f != null && f.constructor === Function && f.length === 2

const autoCons = (init, n) => 
{ const loop = acc => (x, n) =>
    isFunction (x)
      ? acc (x, n)
      : loop (cons (x, acc))
  return loop (nil) (init, n)
}

const map = f => l =>
  l ( (acc, x) => cons (f (x), acc)
    , nil
    )

const filter = f => l =>
  l ( (acc, x) => f (x) ? cons (x, acc) : acc
    , nil
    )

const rcomp = (f, g) =>
  x => g (f (x))

const main = letters =>
  autoCons (map (x => x + x))
           (filter (x => x !== "dd"))
           (map (x => x.toUpperCase()))
           (rcomp, x => x)
           (letters)
           ((x, y) => x + y, "")

console.log (main (autoCons ("a") ("b") ("c") ("d") ("e")))
// AABBCCEE
```

---

**Sorry, my bad**

Let's rewind and look at our initial `List` example

```
// list : List Number
const myList = 
  cons (1, cons (2, cons (3, cons (4, nil))))

console.log
  ( myList ((x, y) => x + y, 0) // 10
  )
```

We conceptualize `myList` as a list of numbers, but we contradict ourselves by calling `myList (...)` like a function.

This is my fault. In trying to simplify the example, I crossed the barrier of abstraction. Let's look at the types of `nil` and `cons` –

```
// nil : List a
// cons : (a, List a) -> List a
```

Given a list of type `List a`, how do we get a value of type `a` out? In the example above (repeated below) we cheat by calling `myList` as a function. This is internal knowledge that only the implementer of `nil` and `cons` should know

```
// myList is a list, not a function... this is confusing...
console.log
  ( myList ((x, y) => x + y, 0) // 10
  )
```

If you look back at our original implementation of `List`,

```
// nil : List a
const nil =
  (c, n) => n

// cons : (a, List a) -> List a
const cons = (x, y = nil) =>
  (c, n) => c (y (c, n), x)
```

I also cheated you giving simplified type annotations like `List a`. What is `List`, exactly?

We're going to address all of this and it starts with our implementation of `List`

**`List`, take 2**

Below `nil` and `cons` have the exact same implementation. I've only fixed the type annotations. Most importantly, I added `reduce` which provides a way to get values "out" of our list container.

The type annotation for `List` is updated to `List a r` – this can be understood as *"a list containing values of type `a` that when reduced, will produce a value of type `r`."*

```
// type List a r = (r, a) -> r

// nil : List a r
const nil =
  (c, n) => n

// cons : (a, List a r) -> List a r
const cons = (x, y = nil) =>
  (c, n) => c (y (c, n), x)

// reduce : ((r, a) -> r, r) -> List a -> r
const reduce = (f, init) => l =>
  l (f, init)
```

Now we can maintain `List` as a sane type, and push all the wonky behavior you want into the `autoCons` function. Below we update `autoCons` to work with our list `acc` using our new `reduce` function

```
const autoCons = (init, n) => 
{ const loop = acc => (x, n) =>
    isFunction (x)
      // don't break the abstraction barrier
      ? acc (x, n)
      // extract the value using our appropriate list module function
      ? reduce (x, n) (acc)
      : loop (cons (x, acc))
  return loop (nil) (init, n)
}
```

So speaking of types, let's examine the type of `autoCons` –

```
autoCons (1)                  // "lambda (x,n) => isFunction (x) ...
autoCons (1) (2)              // "lambda (x,n) => isFunction (x) ...
autoCons (1) (2) (3)          // "lambda (x,n) => isFunction (x) ...
autoCons (1) (2) (3) (add, 0) // 6
```

Well `autoCons` always returns a lambda, but that lambda has a type that we cannot determine – sometimes it returns another lambda of its same kind, other times it returns a completely different result; in this case some number, `6`

Because of this, we cannot easily mix and combine `autoCons` expressions with other parts of our program. If you drop this perverse drive to create variadic curried interfaces, you can make an `autoCons` that is type-able

```
// autoCons : (...a) -> List a r
const autoCons = (...xs) =>
{ const loop = (acc, x = nil, ...xs) =>
    x === nil
      ? acc
      : loop (cons (x, acc), ...xs)
  return loop (nil, ...xs)
}
```

Because `autoCons` now returns a known `List` (instead of the mystery unknown type caused by variadic currying), we can plug an `autoCons` list into the various other functions provided by our `List` module.

```
const c =
  autoCons (1, 2, 3)

const d =
  autoCons (4, 5, 6)

console.log
  ( toArray (c)                         // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  , toArray (map (x => x * x) (d))      // [ 16, 25, 36 ]
  , toArray (filter (x => x != 5) (d))  // [ 4, 6 ]
  , toArray (append (c, d))             // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
  )
```

These kind of mix-and-combine expressions is not possible when `autoCons` returns a type we cannot rely upon. Another important thing to notice is the `List` module gives us a place to expand its functionality. We can easily add functions used above like `map`, `filter`, `append`, and `toArray` – you lose this flexibility when trying to shove everything through the variadic curried interface

Let's look at those additions to the `List` module now – as you can see, each function is well-typed and has behavior we can rely upon

```
// type List a r = (r, a) -> r

// nil : List a r
// cons : (a, List a r) -> List a r
// reduce : ((r, a) -> r, r) -> List a r -> r

// length : List a r -> Int
const length =
  reduce
    ( (acc, _) => acc + 1
    , 0
    )

// map : (a -> b) -> List a r -> List b r
const map = f =>
  reduce
    ( (acc, x) => cons (f (x), acc)
    , nil
    )

// filter : (a -> Bool) -> List a r -> List a r
const filter = f =>
  reduce
    ( (acc,x) =>  f (x) ? cons (x, acc) : acc
    , nil
    )

// append : (List a r, List a r) -> List a r
const append = (l1, l2) =>
  (c, n) =>
    l2 (c, l1 (c, n))

// toArray : List a r -> Array a
const toArray =
  reduce
    ( (acc, x) => [ ...acc, x ]
    , []
    )
```

Even `autoCons` makes sense as part of our module now

```
// autoCons : (...a) -> List a r
const autoCons = (...xs) =>
{ const loop = (acc, x = nil, ...xs) =>
    x === nil
      ? acc
      : loop (cons (x, acc), ...xs)
  return loop (nil, ...xs)
}
```

Add any other functions to the `List` module

```
// nth: Int -> List a r -> a
// isNil : List a r -> Bool
// first : List a r -> a
// rest : List a r -> List a r
// ...
```

Comment: That's a brilliant solution. Build the list in reverse and then use `foldr` so that it seems like you're building the list forwards and using `foldl`. I'd only change one thing, swap the arguments of `c` in `cons` (i.e. `const cons = (x, y) => (c, n) => c(y(c, n), x)`). Hence, you take the accumulator first and the current value second (just as `foldl` specifies). Doing so would change the output of your last example to `"AABBCCEE"` which is actually what I first expected the output to be until I understood what your code was doing. It also allows you to easily convert your list into an array.

Comment: JavaScript Code Guru again! I think you technically invented a new language inside vanilla JS, and this formalization should be shared widely somehow. Amazing. Thank you always!

Comment: I agree with @AaditMShah , the traditional way to construct list as explained in lisp/Scheme textbook is very wrong. Nil should not be  in the tail of the list, instead it should be in the head. Lisp/Scheme brought so much confusion having twisted list structure(0 =nil in the tail)  to programming world.

Comment: @bayesian-study What? No, that's not what I said. The textbook way of defining lists is absolutely correct. Plus, nil can never be the head of the list because of the algebraic structure of the list data type. I just said that building the list backwards and using `foldr` to make it **seem** like you're building the list forwards and using `foldl` is a smart solution.

Comment: @AaditMShah Thanks for the response. I misunderstand what you meant, and I still believe LIsp/Scheme list implementation is very wrong. It should be `((((0=ID),a),b),c)`. Nil on the tail is mess, especially for list of list, you need multiple Nil, but in `((((0=ID),a),b),c)`, you need only one Nil even for list for list.

Comment: @bayesian-study In your example, `0=ID` is still the tail and `c` is the head. It's just that you've written it backwards. Normally, we write lists like `cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, nil)))`. What you're doing `cons(cons(cons(nil, 3), 2), 1)`. It's the exact same data structure except that the arguments of `cons` have been flipped. Hence we write it backwards. Now, your `A(1)(2)(3)` structure is the same as `cons(cons(cons(nil, 1), 2), 3)`. Hence, it's actually equivalent to `[3,2,1]`. However, `[3,2,1].reduceRight(f, x)` is the same as `[1,2,3].reduce(f, x)`. Therefore, `foldr` seems like `foldl`.

Comment: @AaditMShah I disagree. Here's a reference what I'm talking about http://spacetimeprogramminglanguage.github.io/contents/entries/entry0/entry.html and this is completely opposite list structure of Lisp/Scheme and not replaceable by `cons`.

Comment: @bayesian-study For some reason, I think KenOKABE and you are either friends in real life or the same person. Anyway, the example you provided is still a backwards list. The head of `{ { { {} 5 } 2 } 7 }` is `7` and not `{}` because `7` is the outermost value. It's just that you're writing the list backwards. It's not the "complete opposite list structure". In fact, it's the exact same list structure. It's just that you've flipped the arguments. Instead of taking the head first, you're taking the tail first.

Comment: @AaditMShah I still can't aagree. Your perspective of the head of { { { {} 5 } 2 } 7 } is 7 and not {}" simply depends on how you evaluate the list. If you chose to evaluate the outermost value is the first member of the list, then you can conclude "because 7 is the outermost value", but the fact is there is inverse way to evaluate.

Comment: @AaditMShah thanks for your comment. I switched the argument order per your recommendation and the result does feel more natural, especially in JS.

Comment: @user633183 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485931/church-encoding-of-lists-using-right-folds-and-difference-lists This is a new topic related to this topic. Please review, thanks!

Comment: @bayesian-study I added an update to my post in hopes to help you understand the flaw in variadic currying

Comment: @user633183 Thank you very much for your educational update! I'm studying every sentence now, and so far, I'd like to propose something. "Well autoCons always returns a lambda, but that lambda has a type that we cannot determine – sometimes it returns another lambda of its same kind, other times it returns a completely different result; in this case some number, 6"  makes sense,and I just think that instead returning number `6`, returning `(6)` would not cause  the type-mismatch problem. Since now we have `toArray` method, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to admit I haven't read through your linked questions and I'm mainly here for the fun puzzle... but does this help in any way?

I figured you want to differentiate between adding an element (calling with a new value) and running a function on the list (calling with a function). Since I had to somehow pass the function to run, I couldn't get the `(1)` vs `()` syntax to work.

This uses an interface that returns an object with `concat` to extend the list, and `fold` to run a reducer on the list. Again, not sure if it's a complete answer, but it might help you explore other directions.

```js
const Empty = Symbol();

const L = (x, y = Empty) => ({
  concat: z => L(z, L(x, y)),
  fold: (f, seed) => f(x, y === Empty ? seed : y.fold(f, seed))
});

const sum = (a, b) => a + b;


console.log(
  L(1)
    .concat(2).concat(3).concat(4).concat(5).concat(6)
    .fold(sum, 0)
)
```

Comment: My appreciations. Based on your code, I try to refactor to fit the presented format, and post my own answer: Work in progress. I think this is almost done.

Answer (score 0):

## Work in progress

Thanks to the stunning contribution by @user3297291  , I somehow could refactor the code to fit my specification, but not working because I am lost the concept during the implementation :(

The point is whole thing must be curried, and no object.method is involved.

Can anyone "debug" please :)

The initial value is set to the first element, in this example as `1`

I think this is almost done.

```js
const isFunction = f => (typeof f === 'function');

const Empty = Symbol();

const L = (x = Empty) => (y = Empty) => z => isFunction(z)
    ? (() => {
        const fold = f => seed => f(x)(y) === Empty
            ? seed
            : (L)(y)(f);
        return fold(z)(x);
    })()
    : L(z)(L(x)(y));


const sum = a => b => a + b;


console.log(
    L(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(sum)
);
```

### Output

```
 z => isFunction(z)
    ? (() => {
        const fold = f => seed => f(x)(y) === Empty
            ? seed
            : (L)(y)(f);
        return fold(z)(x);
    })()
    : L(z)(L(x)(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the various questions you have but I'm still not sure I entirely understand what you're looking for. On the off chance you're simply looking to represent a linked list, here is a "dumb" representation that does not use clever tricks like overloaded arguments or default parameter values:

```js
const List = (() => {
  const nil = Symbol()

  // ADT
  const Nil = nil
  const Cons = x => xs => ({ x, xs })
  const match = ({ Nil, Cons }) => l => l === nil ? Nil : Cons(l.x)(l.xs)

  // Functor
  const map = f => match({
    Nil,
    Cons: x => xs => Cons(f(x))(map(f)(xs))
  })

  // Foldable
  const foldr = f => z => match({
    Nil: z,
    Cons: x => xs => f(x)(foldr(f)(z)(xs)) // danger of stack overflow!
                                           // https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27
  })

  return { Nil, Cons, match, map, foldr }
})()

const { Nil, Cons, match, map, foldr } = List
const toArray = foldr(x => xs => [x, ...xs])([])

const l = Cons(1)(Cons(2)(Cons(3)(Nil)))

const l2 = map(x => x * 2)(l)
const l3 = map(x => x * 3)(l2)

const a = toArray(l3)
console.log(a) // => [6, 12, 18]
```